# How to use setter to set a value to a attribute which is a private array?

Tags: java, oop, private, setter, getter

I had made an array of roll number so how to give a user input using setter to the private attribute which is roll number.
I made an object of class Students which is a students and tried this`students.for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{(setRollno[i](sc.next()))};`

But it did not worked.

```
class Students{
    private  String[] rollno = new String[1000];
    private  int[] intel = new int[1000];
    private  int[] type = new int[1000];
    private  String[] name = new String[1000];

    public void setRollno(String[] rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }

    public void setName(String[] name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setIntel(int[] intel) {
        this.intel = intel;
    }

    public void setType(int[] type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


    public String[] getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }

    public String[] getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int[] getIntel() {
        return intel;
    }

    public int[] getType() {
        return type;
    }
 }
```

Comment: did you mean `students.setType(` by the `students.(`?

Comment: 1. You can not use the array [i] on a method call like setRollno[i]                 
2. You have to pass that method a string array, not a string

Comment: I want to give an user input to the rollno array using setters.

Comment: So you want to modify only one value of your rollno? If no then tell me and I'll update my answer.

Comment: You may want to use this instead : `students.getRollno()[i] = sc.next();` .

Comment: No i want to give 'n' user inputs (in form of string) using loop to the array 'rollno'.

Comment: I am not allowed to use 'getter' to give the input,I have to use the setter to do the same what you just did now.

Comment: @Berger I took the liberty of adding your comment to my answer if it's ok with you: even though it's a "plus" and TO cna't use it, it may help people having problems with arrays.

Comment: @Nathan : No problem :)

Comment: It's considered bad practice to return a reference to a private collection (including an array). Use `getRollNoAtIndex(int i)` instead. Also, you probably want to have a `Student` class containing a *single* roll no and name, and have a single *array of Students*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setRollno[i](sc.next());` isn't the good syntax. Your function `setRollno` take an array of strings as parameter, and change all the array you have. If that's what you want, you must pass an array of `String`s as parameter:

If you want to set one specific `String` in your `rollno`, you must create another function:

```
setRollNoAtIndex(int i, String s) {
    this.rollno[i] = s;
}
```

If you need to call this in a loop, you can then simply do:

```
for(int i=0; i < n ;i++) {
    students.setRollNoAtIndex(i, sc.next());
}
```

As per [Berger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5612858/berger)'s comment:

The syntax you were trying to use was probably either:

```
for(int i=0; i < n ;i++) {
    students.getRollno()[i] = sc.next();
}
```

or

```
String[] list = new String [1000];
for(int i=0; i < n ;i++) {
    list[i] = sc.next();
}
students.setRollno(list);
```

Comment: I have to input a series of String using a loop.

Comment: @ÄnsuMan Here you go. But you seem quite lost when it comes to arrays in java, maybe you should read some tutorial first.

Comment: I am a beginner to JAVA and could not figure out how to use setter to give a user input.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly I'm misunderstanding the aim of your data structure, but it sounds like you're trying to create a collection of student data all in one place. If this is the case then I'd strongly recommend creating a `Student` class which represents just one student at a time, and then using one or more standard types from the Java Collection Framework to make it easy to find a particular student.

For example, your `Student` class could simply contain fields which hold the roll number, name, and other data for one student. Then, assuming that you'll want to find students quickly by roll number you could create a `Map<String, Student>` where the map keys are roll numbers and the corresponding map value is the student who has that roll number. Simply put a new `Student` object into the `Map` after constructing it. If you need to find students by name then you could create a `Map<String, Collection<Student>>` (because more than one student might have the same name) and put each new `Student` object into this name map after constructing it.

This is likely to lead to code which is a lot easier to read, maintain, and use than an all-in-one custom collection class such as the one shown in your question.

As a rough code example:

```
String rollNumber = getNewRollNumber(); // wherever roll numbers come from
String name = getStudentName(); // wherever the name comes from
Student newStudent = new Student(rollNumber, name, etc);
studentsByRollNumber.put(rollNumber, newStudent);
studentsByName.computeIfAbsent(name,
        n -> new ArrayList<>(1)).add(student);

Student studentWithParticularRollNumber =
        studentsByRollNumber.get("123456");
Collection<Student> studentsWithParticularName =
        studentsByName.get("Perry, Fred");
```

The `Map#computeIfAbsent` method will create a new `ArrayList` under the given student name only if no entry already exists under that name, or will fetch the existing list if that name already exists in the map, and then will put the new student into the list.

Within the call to `computeIfAbsent` the lambda expression `t -> new ArrayList<>(1)` simply means "take the value of the map key, and whatever it is just create a new ArrayList of size one". It simply guarantees that if there is not already a `Collection<Student>` stored under the given student name then a new `ArrayList<Student>` will be created and stored there.

Comment: This is extremely true, I should've said so in my answer. I was focused on solving the problem and didn't realize the underlying problematic. Though it seems TO is fairly new to JAVA (he said it actually) and probably doesn't yet grasp the usage of collections.

Comment: After your edit: I believe your use of a lambda is a bit too hard to understand for someone that isn't used to collections (but that's just my point of view)

Comment: Lambda expressions are pretty funky looking at first, I agree. The answer has been edited to add a brief note about the meaning of that particular lambda expression. Exactly the same thing can be done without using a lambda, but the alternative takes up four lines and is much uglier.

Answer (score 0):

I think that design of this class is not correct, because we have access to internal arrays directly. Moreover, in that case you do not have to init all these arrays on new instance creation. I offer a little bit another implementation of this class, that I found more suitable for this goal:

```
final class Students {
    private static final int TOTAL = 1000;

    private final Map<String, Student> students = new HashMap<>(TOTAL);

    public void setName(String rollno, String name) {
        getOrCreateStudent(rollno).name = name;
    }

    public void setIntel(String rollno, int intel) {
        getOrCreateStudent(rollno).intel = intel;
    }

    public void setType(String rollno, int type) {
        getOrCreateStudent(rollno).type = type;
    }

    public Set<String> getRollno() {
        return students.keySet();
    }

    public String getName(String rollno) {
        return students.getOrDefault(rollno, Student.NULL).name;
    }

    public int getIntel(String rollno) {
        return students.getOrDefault(rollno, Student.NULL).intel;
    }

    public int getType(String rollno) {
        return students.getOrDefault(rollno, Student.NULL).type;
    }

    private Student getOrCreateStudent(String rollno) {
        Student student = students.get(rollno);

        if (student == null)
            students.put(rollno, student = new Student(rollno));

        return student;
    }

    private static final class Student {
        private static final Student NULL = new Student(null);

        private final String rollno;
        private int intel;
        private int type;
        private String name;

        public Student(String rollno) {
            this.rollno = rollno;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This example was written over your question. Then you can move Student class outside Students class and replace it with Map<String, Student> students collection. Anyway, my point is that in you question you have choosen wrong implementation.